# How to look up numerical value of one column in a comma seperated values of another column in T-Sql?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table with 3 fields as shown below and would like select only the rows in which [NewFacility] has the matching [Facility] value in it.

NewFacility field has the numerical values separated by comma.

Present table:

```
Item    Facility    NewFacility
Car 1               1
Van 1               2,4
Bus 3               2,4
Truck   4           2,3,4
```

Expected Result:

```
Item    Facility    NewFacility
Car 1               1
Truck   4           2,3,4
```

#### Table info

[image]

Comment: Storing a comma-separated list of values in a column is a poor design decision.

Comment: Can `Item` have repeted values?

Comment: Agreed on poor design.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example:

```
SELECT Item
     , Facility
     , NewFacility
     , ISNULL(i.value('n[1]','varchar(10)'), '') 
     , ISNULL(i.value('n[2]','varchar(10)'), '') 
     , ISNULL(i.value('n[3]','varchar(10)'), '') 
FROM (SELECT Item
           , Facility
           , NewFacility
           , CONVERT(XML,'<r><n>' + REPLACE(NewFacility, ',', '</n><n>') + '</n></r>') AS X 
      FROM [Table_Name])  Spt 
CROSS APPLY Spt.X.nodes('/r') x(i) 
WHERE Facility in (i.value('n[1]','varchar(10)')
                , i.value('n[2]','varchar(10)') 
                , i.value('n[3]','varchar(10)'))
```

This works by converting the string to XML and accessing the comma-delimited string as a series of nodes.  For each potential node you have to hard-code the position with another 'n[x]' value or come up with an iterative solution that pokes through all the positions if you have, say, an ever-expanding number of facilities.